# Unexpected condition error in a ksh script

Tags: ksh

I am new to ksh programming and wonder why the following code does not work:

```
#!/bin/ksh
set -A tables 44 45 46 47 48 49 50

for i in ${tables[@]}
  do
  if [[$i -eq 48 ]]; then
  echo "processing table${i}_Ge65"
  echo "processing table${i}_Lt65"
  fi
  echo "processing table${i}_A"
  echo "processing table${i}_B"
done
```

The error message is that

```
[[44: not found [No such file or directory]
```

for every number in the array. It seems to me that ksh treats $i as a filename instead of an expression. Any suggestion on why and how to fix this?

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing space after `[[`:

```
if [[ $i -eq 48 ]]; then
# ...^
```

This happens because `[[` is actually a *command* not just syntax and, like any other command, a space is required to separate the command from the arguments.